# vuejs v-html render bingding value delayed: must trigger with a mouse click in and out of textarea control

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have following issue:
There is a textarea which is v-model with a value.
That value is rendered with {{{value}}} , my issue is:
When I change the textarea control content with a javascript, that {{{value}}} will not be rendered right away. I must do a click in and out of textarea.
live fiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/matiascx/bbpmn39e/3/

html is here:
    
        `<div id="app">
      <textarea name="test" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" v-model="content"></textarea>
      <hr>
      <button @click="insertTag">insert strong tag</button>
      {{{ content }}}
    </div>`

js is here:
    
            `new Vue({
        el: '#app',
      data: {
        content: 'this is the inital content data'
      },
      methods: {
        insertTag: function(){
                var textel = document.getElementById('textarea');
          textel.value = textel.value + '<em>this is em</em>';
        }
      }
    })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic VueJS paradigm is to acts on data, not on html widget value.
`insertTag` function should be something like:

```
insertTag: function() {
   this.content = this.content + '<em>this is em</em>';
}
```

You can see working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gannunziata/bbpmn39e/4/)